# When extending state, how do I implement shared actions as I can for shared selectors?

Tags: angular, ngxs

#### Problem

When inheriting state with NGXS, there's a great technique in the docs for sharing selectors. It's very useful as it means selectors for all child states are only defined once.

I would like to take the same approach with actions but I can't figure it out. How can I go about this so I don't have to create a set of concrete actions for every inherited state?

#### Thoughts so far

The NGXS gitbook shows how this works with inherited selectors:
https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/v/master/concepts/select#inheriting-selectors

I've tried looking at the `ngxs-entity` plugin and found a function called `generateActionObject()`:

https://github.com/ngxs-labs/entity-state/blob/master/src/lib/internal.ts

This feels like the right kind of approach, but I can't see through the fog and figure out which is the first step I need to take to go about this.

#### My context

I am implementing a generic `ListingModule` in Angular which defines a base state class, `ListingState`. This contains standard things such as current page, rows per page, sort options etc.

The child modules which will use the generic listing module will each need a separate slice of the store to contain their state.

A rough example:

```
ListingChildStateA
{ 
  numberOfRows, 
  currentPage 
} 

ListingChildStateB
{ 
  numberOfRows, 
  currentPage 
} 

ListingChildStateC
{ 
  numberOfRows, 
  currentPage 
}
```

I know this is a good usage scenario for state inheritance. And with shared selectors as per the NGXS docs I'm half way to getting this nailed.

#### Example

I need to implement *something* like this.

```
@Dispatch()
function setPage() {
   new generateAction(SetPage, 'ListingChildStateA');
}


class BaseListingState {
...
@Action(SetPage)
setPage(ctx: StateContext<BaseListingState>) {
  ...
}
```

So dispatching the action this way would mean the slice named `ListingChildStateA` of the store would be changed and none of the others would be mutated.

I know this is wrong but I'm trying to use it to describe my intentions. I am sure there must be a way to make actions more generic, shareable as the `ngxs-entity` plugin is doing something like this.

#### What next?

Can anybody please help me with how I go about best using state inheritance with shared selectors *and* actions?

Thanks.

Comment: this depends on what do you mean by "shared actions", because there is no concept of "shared actions"

Comment: I'm trying to follow the terminology set out in the NGXS gitbook. But my meaning is being able to create a set of actions which can operate on the correct part of the store according to the inherited, child state's key. 

Will update question to improve clarity.

Comment: let's move a little away from the `@Dispatch`, it's just a plugin. Sharing actions and selectors are different approaches. You can't create one generic action for 3 states as you will have to create 3 action handlers in your 3 child states. Those actions handlers should listen to different actions, as if you've got 3 action handlers that listen to the same action - they all will be invoked when that action is dispatched

Comment: Thanks Shadow. Yep sure this makes perfect sense. I am hoping to find a way to generate unique actions in some higher-order function.

Comment: P.S. you can ask this question in our official NGXS slack channel, you'd get more answers there :)

Comment: Cool man I will do that, thanks

Comment: Open to any more input if anybody else has anything?

Comment: @johnnygri I think you are misunderstanding the concept of the base state. The base state will have its own action and selector. You will implement ListStateA, B, and C by extending this base state so that each specific state doesn't have to write actions and selectors for that base state.

Comment: Thanks SLee but it is impossible to extend a base state's static selector methods and I'm fairly sure extending action methods doesn't work as the @Action() decorator ties the method to a specific action class instance.